# Change packaging to war causes 404

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, war

I've got a Maven project with Java Enterprise 7, Java 8 and I use IntelliJ.
When I add the  attribut with war in the pom.xml, I get 404 in my browser trying to get the index page. I didn't get this error before the changing packaging to war.

My project structure can be seen in the picture.

[image: project structure]

I noticed that my index.xhtml is missing in the out Directory after chanaging to war. Why? Thanks for your help :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <display-name>JSF Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I changed my project structure after the war-plugin-specification as mentioned in the answer.

[image]

Problem still exists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MyGroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>Application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src\main\web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <id>corp1</id>
            <name>Corporate Repository</name>
            <url>file:///home/myfolder/.m2</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.20.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It is a glassfish 5.0.0 Server.

Comment: Can you show your web.xml please ?

Comment: I added the web.xml

Answer (score 1):

normally in a maven war project the structure looks something like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   └── webapp
│   │       ├── WEB-INF
│   │       └── index.html
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
└── target
```

I see you have: `/src/main/java` but the web app is in `/web`
this will not work in a maven web project...

Also it looks like you have the pom.xml in the /web project and not in the root of the project.

It also looks like you have a `/lib` folder in the root of your project. All the dependencies there should be added to the pom.xml file as dependencies and the lib folder will then be generated by maven in the webapp folder in the resulting war

So think about reorganising your code to conform to the maven structure. As Maven works with convention over configuration this is always a good idea :-)

The target folder is only used for the build.

Comment: IntelliJ created this structure after I choose to create a Java EE project. I assume the web directory is the webapp folder?

Comment: Yep, you must respect the Maven structure, and check the configuration of your 'maven-war-plugin'.

Comment: I think you generated a java-ee application with intellij and not a maven project. You added maven later it seems...

Comment: Can I leave target, out, etc outside the main directory? I can not find the specification in the war plugin.

Comment: target is the build folder for maven and can be thrown away whenever you want. it is only needed for the build and will be created again when build again. Try `mvn clean` and it will be thrown away

Comment: I cleaned, compiled and deployed with success. Still getting 404.

Comment: did you add dependencies to the pom for all the jars in the /lib folder?

Comment: All dependencies are in the pom.xml, I also deleted the lib Folder. I got exactly the same project structure apart from the .iml and .idea being in root. I refactored the name of the web folder to webapp.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml and tell me to what server you deploy and stuff like that? and try to generate a simple webapp from with `mvn archetype:generate` to see if you did it all correctly...